# Problems using CoreLocation and iBeacons

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon

I want to build an app with indoor localization (I know Bluetooth is not that precise, but rough values are enough at first).
My problem is, that I am only able to range the beacons I placed in the room for 10 seconds after turning Bluetooth off and on. The strange thing is, that turning Bluetooth off and on resolves the problem (again for 10 seconds).

Here's the code snippet of my simple test app:

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons inRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region
{
   BOOL beaconFound = NO;
   for(CLBeacon *beacon in beacons)
   {
       if(beacon.proximity == CLProximityNear)
       {
           _textView.text = @"A Beacon is Near!";
           beaconFound = YES;
       }
   }
   if(!beaconFound)
       _textView.text = @"No Beacon is Near";
}
```

Is it some kind of energy saving on iOS? I don't have any other explanation for this, but it seems that no one else has this problem.
I also tried ranging a simulated iBeacon on an iPad but got the same results.

I want to be able, to range the beacons constantly, am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What kind of beacons are you using?  I have heard of similar behavior with some models.

Comment: I am using Kontakt beacons. [link](http://kontakt.io/)

Comment: Check out this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21522383/problems-with-kontakt-io-beacons. Your experience is slightly different, but both suggest something may be wrong with the beacons.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are doing the ranging in the foreground or background.
I believe if you are doing it in the background iOS will only allows you to do the ranging for a period of time before the locationManager stop.

The other thing is you only check for CLProximityNear. You might want to try check for three zone. I did test startRangingBeaconsInRegion and the result was jumping back and forth between Near and Far sometimes Immediate. Hope this help.

```
switch (beacon.proximity) {
     case CLProximityImmediate:
          _textView.text = @"A Beacon is Immediate!";
          beaconFound = YES;
          break;
     case CLProximityNear:
          _textView.text = @"A Beacon is Near!";
          beaconFound = YES;
          break;
     case CLProximityFar:
          _textView.text = @"A Beacon is Far!";
          beaconFound = YES;
          break;
     default:
          break;
}
```

Comment: No I am doing the ranging in foreground. I also tried the solution you described but got the same problem. After 10 seconds I am not able to range any of my 6 beacons. #

Answer (score 0):

Try removing this qualifier:

if(beacon.proximity == CLProximityNear)

I suspect that your distance from the beacon is usually returning a different value (perhaps CLProximityFar or CLProximityImmediate).  If true, the reason you would see results for the  first 10 seconds is because during that time the proximity value bounces around a lot.  This might cause you to get matches to CLProximityNear during that time before the distance estimate settles out.